# Is there special meaning for ()() syntax in Lua

Tags: lua, torch

I see this type of syntax a lot in some Lua source file I was reading lately, what does it mean, especially the second pair of brackets
An example, line 8 in
https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn/blob/master/model/LSTM.lua

```
local LSTM = {}
function LSTM.lstm(input_size, rnn_size, n, dropout)
  dropout = dropout or 0 

  -- there will be 2*n+1 inputs
  local inputs = {}
  table.insert(inputs, nn.Identity()())  -- line 8
  -- ...
```

The source code of `nn.Identity`
https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/Identity.lua

********** UPDATE **************

The ()() pattern is used in torch library 'nn' a lot. The first pair of bracket creates an object of the container/node, and the second pair of bracket references the depending node.

For example, y = nn.Linear(2,4)(x) means x connects to y, and the transformation is linear from 1*2 to 1*4.
I just understand the usage, how it is wired seems to be answered by one of the answers below.

Anyway, the usage of the interface is well documented below.
https://github.com/torch/nngraph/blob/master/README.md

Comment: If there is a question then a good way to resolve that problem is to pull out the expression `nn.Identity()` and give it a meaningful name. For example (but with a nearly meaningless name since I don't know what to call it): `local identityProvider = nn.Identity()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In complement to Yu Hao's answer let me give some Torch related precisions:

- `nn.Identity()` creates an identity module,
- `()` called on this module triggers `nn.Module` [`__call__`](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/b7aa53d96fbb6c0f2eaa1976b28c5cf12edf1ced/Module.lua#L232-L240) (thanks to Torch class system that properly hooks up this into the metatable),
- by default this `__call__` method performs a forward / backward,
- but here [torch/nngraph](https://github.com/torch/nngraph) is used and **nngraph overrides** this method as you can see [here](https://github.com/torch/nngraph/blob/eb65b3602cdf3214ff671d5422521ad414f1c3b0/init.lua#L22-L45).

In consequence every `nn.Identity()()` calls has here for effect to return a `nngraph.Node({module=self})` node where self refers to the current `nn.Identity()` instance.

--

**Update**: an illustration of this syntax in the context of [LSTM-s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short_term_memory) can be found [here](http://apaszke.github.io/lstm-explained.html#computing-gate-values):

```
local i2h = nn.Linear(input_size, 4 * rnn_size)(input)  -- input to hidden
```

> If you’re unfamiliar with `nngraph` it probably seems strange that we’re constructing a module and already calling it once more with a graph node. What actually happens is that **the second call converts the `nn.Module` to `nngraph.gModule` and the argument specifies it’s parent in the graph**.

Answer (score 14):

No, `()()` has no special meaning in Lua, it's just two call operators `()` together.

The operand is possibly a function that returns a function(or, a table that implements `call` metamethod). For example:

```
function foo()
  return function() print(42) end
end

foo()()   -- 42
```

Answer (score 2):

- The first () calls the init function and the second () calls the call function
- If the class doesn't posses either of these functions then the parent functions are called .
- In the case of nn.Identity()() the nn.Identity has neither init function nor a call function hence the Identity parent nn.Module's init and call functions called .Attaching an illustration

  ```
  require 'torch'

  -- define some dummy A class
  local A = torch.class('A')
  function A:__init(stuff)
    self.stuff = stuff
    print('inside __init of A')
  end

  function A:__call__(arg1)
  print('inside __call__ of A')
  end

  -- define some dummy B class, inheriting from A
  local B,parent = torch.class('B', 'A')

  function B:__init(stuff)
    self.stuff = stuff
    print('inside __init of B')
  end

  function B:__call__(arg1)
  print('inside __call__ of B')
  end
  a=A()()
  b=B()()
  ```

  **Output**

  ```
  inside __init of A
  inside __call__ of A
  inside __init of B
  inside __call__ of B
  ```

Another code sample

```
    require 'torch'

    -- define some dummy A class
    local A = torch.class('A')
    function A:__init(stuff)
      self.stuff = stuff
      print('inside __init of A')
    end

    function A:__call__(arg1)
    print('inside __call__ of A')
    end

    -- define some dummy B class, inheriting from A
    local B,parent = torch.class('B', 'A')

    b=B()()
```

**Output**

```
    inside __init of A
    inside __call__ of A
```